# How to find the amount of \n in an arduino String

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to find the indexes of \n in a string on my arduino. This is the code i'm using:

```
String string = data;
int del;
int count = 0;
while(true){
  if(string.indexOf("\n", (del + 1)) == -1){
    break;
    }
  else{
    del = string.indexOf("\n", (del + 1));
    count++;
    }
  }
```

For whatever reason, it's just returning 0 no matter what. My goal would be for the count variable to contain the amount of lines contained in the variable. Any advice would be great.

Comment: Please don't tag with two languages. If this is just C, that's fine.

Comment: Either learn how the String class works, or don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `int del=-1`.

Other than that, I don't see a problem. Could be that you might need to use single quotes like this `'\n'`, indicating a character and not double quotes.